# Google search results limits

Tags: python, search, google-search

I tried to search in google search engine the word "sunday".

The total number of results is `1.390.000.000`. However I can see only the first 420 results, until 42 page of results.

Is there any way to take all the results of google search?

Comment: Are you using a library ? If so, which one ?

Comment: @TrakJohnson no I use the simple search of google. Is there any library for this purpose which give back the full results. Because I tried to find one but I didn't find.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `google` module to control the number of results from your query.

Install it using `pip`:

```
pip install google
```

Usage:

```
from google import search

n = 10  # number of results
query = 'sunday'
results = google.search(query, stop=n)  # returns a generator

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Before using this method, keep this in mind about the `pause` parameter:

> pause (float) - Lapse to wait between HTTP requests. A lapse too long will make the search slow, but a lapse too short may cause Google to block your IP.
>   Your mileage may vary!

[Docs](http://pythonhosted.org/google/)

Answer (score 2):

This 'feature' of google - and other search engines - applies to the web interface too. The claimed number of matches on the first page is not reflected in the actual number of results returned.

For example, if you [search Google for "Systematic Literature Review"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=systematic%20%22literature%20review%22&oq=systematic%20%22literature%20review%22)  it will claim a few milion results on the first page, but if you go to page 3 (at 100 results/page) it will 'revise' the estimate to 200-300 results.

This seems too high in the initial estimate but may be a problem with filtering large datasets and is possibly forgivable. However it is definitely too small a number of actual results returned for this topic. Bing and DuckDuckGo are similar. Google Scholar claims 11k or so results but returns a server error if you try going beyond 1000.

Speculating: this might be in order to encourage people to change their search terms, rather than return a huge number of results that are then filtered programmatically locally (which is what I would like to do!).

This isn't an answer to getting more results I'm afraid, but it is an explanation that the problem is not the library, it's the search engine(s).