# Scraping first 10 links from google search for large number of records

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have 63,000 strings and i want to iterate over all and search for each string in google and store the first ten links in a new column separated with a ",". I have tried the following code but its too slow.Please suggest me any other way to scrape the links

```
    try:
        from googlesearch import search
    except ImportError: 
        print("No module named 'google' found")
    query = "xyz"
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=5):
        print(j)
```

Comment: what does "pause=5" do? To speed up your code reduce this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError: 
    print("No module named 'google' found")
query = "xyz"
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=1):
    print(j)
```

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284501/google-search-results-limits) 
"pause (float) - Lapse to wait between HTTP requests. A lapse too long will make the search slow, but a lapse too short may cause Google to block your IP. Your mileage may vary!"

Comment: thank u very much for your answer but the time it is taking for scraping is very high due to size of data even though the pause is 1.

Comment: you could try to remove pause or reduce it more?

Comment: I had tried to put pause at 0.5 but after some iterations i am getting 503:service not available error

Comment: how fast is taking to run when you use 1? also how fast do you want it to be?

Comment: i guess it will take around 70 hours for scraping 63,000.